# Typescript interfaces: Any way to describe "<Property> of <Interface>"

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

Quick example:

```
public processList<T extends {}>(list: T[], targetProperty: ???) {
    // do something with target property...
}
```

I would like to have a type that describes the interface of `T`. So if `T` would be of type `{ a: string, b: boolean }` then I would like to have `targetProperty` to accept either `a` or `b`.

I know i could solve this problem by using a string which holds the name of the target property. Meaning something like `targetProperty = 'myProperty'` and then `item[targetProperty] = ...` But I think this is likely to break in future (for example when the interface of T changes).

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or are there any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `keyof T`......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to declare a type of variable as SomeInterface.Property since Typescript neither on its own merits nor on the grounds of Javascript runtime is not a reflecting language. There is no way to have a runtime check established in such a simple fashion.

As of static checking, there is an index type query `keyof`.

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}

type K1 = keyof Person; // "name" | "age" | "location"
type K2 = keyof Person[];  // "length" | "push" | "pop" | "concat" | ...
```

The result produced by this query is a type itself, so you declare additional generic constraints as

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
     return obj[key];  // Inferred type is T[K]
}
```

**Source**: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html